# How to merge JSON data into an existing PDF in Node?

Tags: node.js, json, pdf

Say I have a PDF of a government form. I have a JSON of data with which I'd like to populate the PDF. What would be a good way, using Node, to merge the data into the PDF and create a new PDF?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the form-filling tools of [PDF-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) are going to do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in this way.

You can create a route e.g `/pdf/create` where you populate the form. In that form you set the submit form route to `/pdf/save` now if user modified some of the fields then you get the updated value else the default one and generate pdf based on that.

Comment: But what are the mechanics of populating the form?

In our scenario, a PDF will exist on.a server. The client will send the JSON to the server, and the server needs to create and save a version of the PDF with the incoming JSON’s data.

Comment: @LukeSeemann if you are using express with a template engine then pass value to template e.g https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/web-weather-app/blob/master/src/app.js#L25-L27, view https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/web-weather-app/blob/master/src/views/index.pug and https://github.com/arifmahmudrana/web-weather-app/blob/master/src/app.js#L43-L167 but the method can be post this is just an example let me know if anymore deails you need.